# How to know in log4j , that ERROR level is triggered?

Tags: java, log4j

How to know in log4j , that ERROR level is triggered. In my code I have written like If an exception occurs i.e if an ERROR level is triggered then I will show log file path in console and wont show any message for other levels.

Comment: You mean something like isErrorEnabled()? http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/spi/AbstractLogger.html#isErrorEnabled%28%29

Answer (score 0):

In Log4j you can configure different levels in the log4j.properties or xml file which ever you choose to use. 
There is some predefined pattern with the error levels and runs from lower to upper.
Lowest id Debug its in this sequence.

1.Debug
2. Warn
3. Error etc

So if you want only Error messages then configure the Error level to Error. you wot get Debug and Warn

If you configure Debug you get everything

Ex.

```
<logger name="org.springframework...">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the point of separating the code from the configuration.
E.g., your code could look like this:

```
try {
    someMethod();
} catch (SomeException e) {
    log.error("Error!!! " + e.getMessage());
}
```

And in your log4j configuration, your configure your log to output only ERROR level messages:

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# Just an example of a pattern layout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout   
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```